# Exchange: Allow non-owner of meeting to change location/room

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app, outlook-2013

We've been asked to do something with rooms and not too sure how..

- We have 4 rooms at a conference that can be booked by any of the sales team
- We have a group of admins that should be able to change these meetings, including:

  - Change times (done)
  - Change Room

We're ok with the time change, setting them as owner on the \Calendar folder of the room mailbox allows this.

What I cant find is a way to allow them to change the room/location. They can type over the "location" field, and save this, but the meeting stays in the "old" room's calendar.

eg: Bob books a meeting in room 1. An hour later, Fred needs to book it - Fred is friends with the boss, so it must be done. The admin can open Bob's meeting and see attendees, but cannot use the scheduling assistant to select a new room, and overtyping the "Location" field just changes text, it stays in room1's calendar.

Any idea how we can allow these admins to change the room for a meeting they do not own?

Answer (score 1):

Does the "admin" have delegate access to Bob calendar?  That's the only way they'll have the right to change a meeting room.  Bob would need to delegate the right to the admin.  This is not a problem of the meeting room, rather a problem with delegate access or the "organizer".

Edit 1:

From the meeting room side, one option might be to give the admin the power to decline a meeting.  If nothing else, that would force "bob" to re-book a different room.

Comment: Thanks Eric, i feared this - I'm not sure we can give delegate access to all the sales folks, but I'll leave this as a last resort solution. As for meeting room delegate, this is another possibility, but the issue we're going to have to solve is moving rooms post-booking.